# How to redirect subfolder from non-www to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress and set with http://www.example.com/ and I want to redirect from the non-www to www one.

The follow sample works for http://example.com to http://www.example.com,

but i also want the following redirection which doesn't work in the current implementation.

//subfoler
http://example.com/wp-admin/ to http://www.example.com/wp-admin/

//with querystring
http://example.com/?p=1034 to http://www.example.com/?p=1034

The current goes to 403 Forbidden, do you have any suggestion?

Should i work with .htaccess or 403 error page to perform simple redirection?

Here is my setting in the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

thanks

More information about my site.

I have used cloudflare and set the following  value to my site. Does it matter?

```
Type        Name         Value  
 A      sample.com    XX.xx.xx.xx  
 A          www       xx.xx.xx.xx  
 A            *       xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: That should work, are there any other rewrite rules that could interfere?

Comment: I have just updated my website setting.Does it matter with my current configuration ?

Comment: I have figured out the problems. It is my server setting, i should set the root_server in the ngix configuration to be www.example.com example.com